# ruby on rails session data returns false even when data exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a code like,

`session[:my_data] = 'abcd'`

and when i try to get,

`puts session.has_key?("my_data")` then it returns `false` always.

Comment: `session.has_key?(:my_data)`

Comment: yes, but i am getting other data using same syntax

Comment: then: `session["my_data"] = 'abcd'`, just be consistent

Comment: i just want to check whether key exist or not

Comment: When i try this, i get nil for session["my_data"].  In other words, the session does not behave like a HashWithIndifferentAccess (which is used for storing `params` in the controller, for example, allowing you to get `params[:foo]` or `params["foo"]`.  When you say `yes, but i am getting other data using same syntax `, can you explain where and how you are doing this?

Comment: see this http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F

Answer (score 1):

Ruby allows any object to be a hash key. If the hash key is a symbol, you will not be able to access it using a string.

In this case, you have various options:

- convert the string to a symbol

  `session.has_key?("my_data".to_sym)`
- use Rails' `with_indifferent_access` method to allow both symbol and string queries on the hash

  `s = session.with_indifferent_access
  puts s.has_key?("my_data")`